# Error "No value given for one or more required parameters"

Tags: oledbexception

```
    private void rdoCategory_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Recipe ORDER BY CategoryDesc";
        dbCommand = new OleDbCommand(sql,dbConnection);

            dbAdapter.SelectCommand = dbCommand;
            dbAdapter.Fill(ds, "Recipe");

            dgvRecipes.DataSource = ds.Tables["Recipe"];



    }
```

Comment: I am trying to fetch data from access to print on a data grid view, but it keeps on giving me that error, I have the exact same code of Form_load and it works perfectly fine, the difference is only "ORDER BY"..

Comment: can u provide a brief description of the problem..

Comment: Post your stacktrace, where is the exception thrown?

Comment: There is no background information here, nor language tag, so voting to close.